# What is the difference between commutatitivity and distributivity?

Tags: terminology

Inspired by linearity property, I see that operator `A` distributes over sum: $A(\sum {f_i}) = \sum {(A(f_i))}\;\,$. What do I have between A and ∑: commutativity or distributivity? The fact that I can switch the order, $A\sum = \sum A$, implies commutativity. Meantime, we see that `A` distributes over sums in this case. Can I say that commutative and distributive are the same things since `A` distributes over `∑` iff `A` and `∑` are commutative?

**update** 
I consider A and ∑ as operators (matrices) over functions (aka vectors) $f_i\,$. Might be I just confuse multiple definitions of the sum (if there are any). For instance, sum of vector elements is not the same as sum of multiple vectors.

Comment: Commutativity is $ab=ba$. Distributivity is $a(b+c)=ab+ac$, or $(a+b)c=ac+bc$, or both. One relates on operation with itself, the other two operations. I guess this should help clear out your confusion.

Comment: Can you represent the example in my form and repeat the argument?

Comment: What else can I say?

Comment: If the sum is finite and $A$ and $B_i$ are numbers than what you have is regular old distributivity.

Comment: Do you mean that this is not commutativity? `A` and `∑` do not commute in my example?

Comment: @Val Is $A$ a function of some sort? In such case -- which seems to the case here -- make it explicit.

Comment: I think of it like operator

Comment: Then it is neither.

Comment: $A$ looks like a homomorphism of an additive group.

Comment: Well, in this case one says that "$A$ commutes with sums" if you may, but that is a less formal way to say things.

Comment: A is distributive = A commutes with sums?

Comment: It's the multiplication of a ring that is distributive. This "multiplication" can even be composition in a ring of operators.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld And how does it clarify the indicated relationship with commutativity?

Comment: The elements of a ring of operators can commute, but summation of operators is *never* an element of that ring, so you cannot say that an operator commutes with summation.

Comment: But I clearly see that it is. Isn't it? What is commutativity if not A∑ = ∑A? How is it never commutative if it is?

Comment: Val: Suppose the domain of $A$ is $D$. The domain of $A\sum_{i=1}^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples consisting of elements of $D$. Since $A$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n$ commute as operators, the domain of $A$ must be the set of all $n$-tuples of elements of $D$ union $D$. Unless $D$ is empty, we get a contradiction to the axiom of foundation.

Comment: Good point. Actually, I concocted my example using differentiation, as a model for A. You know the identity that sum of direvatives is a direvative of the sum. So, $B_n$ must also be functions. Operators operate on functions. Don't they? And, not all functions are constants. I have renamed $B_n$ to $f_n$ to remove the confusion.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld What if we take the domain of $A$ to be the union of $D^n$ for all $n$ and let $A$ act componentwise on a tuple of elements of $D$. True we are defining a new $\hat{A}$ on this union of tuples, but $A$ and $\hat{A}$ encode the same information. Then for a tuple $T=(T_1,\ldots,T_N)$ we have $\hat{A}\Sigma(T)=\hat{A}(T_1+\ldots+T_n)=A(T_1+\ldots+T_n)=A(T_1)+\ldots+A(T_n)=\Sigma A(T_i)=\Sigma\hat{A}(T)$. So $\hat{A}$ and $\Sigma$ commute. Hence we can say that it is true $A$ commutes with $\Sigma$ to the same extend as we can identify $A$ with $\hat{A}$.

Comment: @ABC Then the domain of operation of $\Sigma$ is different from that of $\hat A$.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is defined on tuples. You input a tuple, it returns the sum of its entries. This last you can see then as a $1$-tuple and then is an element of the set of tuple again.

Comment: @ABC What, then, is $\Sigma\Sigma$, and does that compare in anyway with how the rest of the world defines it?

Comment: Ok, I must figure out what the sum is and how can we differentiate the sum first. Since Σ produces a constant, derivative of sum is always 0 and I do not understand how the sum of direvatives is derivative of sums then.

Comment: If we interpret $A$ as a map and $\sum$ as sum, then $A(\sum f_i) = \sum(A(f_i))$ kind of looks like half of the statement "$A$ is linear", doesn't it?

Comment: @kahen Yes, this is exactly how I came here. I started to think that linear operator is one that commutes with the sum operator. This also reminds me that ∑ is a matrix and the result of $\sum {f_i}$ is a function rather than a constant!

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Let $T=(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$ be a tuple. $\Sigma(T)$ is the $1$-tuple $(T_1+\ldots+T_n)$. Then $\Sigma\Sigma(T)$ is again the same $1$-tuple $(T_1+\ldots+T_n)$ as $\Sigma$ adds the elements of a tuple. The problem is not how people see it. Structures and formalism in math are made to aid thinking, not to limit it. Val is seeing a similarity between commutativity and associativity, because there is one. It is not that $A$ per se commutes with $\Sigma$ as you pointed out, but that $\hat{A}$ commutes with $\Sigma$. $\hat{A}$ and $A$ are not the same thing when written in the common...

Comment: formalism in mathematics. But that formalism can't limit the fact that $\hat{A}$ and $A$ contain pretty much the same kind of information. So, there is a way of 'seeing' that commutativity=distributivity that Val is seeing, which is by 'seeing' $\hat{A}$ and $A$ as the same thing. They are not, but they 'can be seen' as the same.

Comment: Do you mean that A applies to $F=[\vec f_1 \vec f_2 \cdots]$, the matrix of column-vectors $\vec f_i$ whereas  matrix ∑, which consists of all 1s, applies to the $F^T = [\vec f_1 \vec f_2 \ldots]^T$, the matrix of row-vectors $\vec f_i$ so that the first column of $F^T$ is a vector of first components of $\vec f_i$, which, applied to ∑, produces the first component of their sum? This way, I see why the informational content ($F=F^T$) admits the commutation of A and ∑, yet, not the blind syntactic switch. I wonder how matematicians always see how objects should be transposed to fit each other.

Comment: Please define the domain and range of your operators A and $\sum$. Without that, talking about commutativity is pointless.

Comment: @TenaliRaman Why do people teach the pointless things like "vector space", "matrix", "function" and derivative of sum is the sum of derivatives?

Comment: Do you understand my question? Given two operators A and B, AB = A(B(x)). Unless B's range is A's domain, A(B(x)) does not make sense. Similarly, BA = B(A(x)) therefore, A's range has to be B's domain. Finally, for AB = BA to be true, A's range has to be same as B's range.

Thereby, unless you define A and B's domain and range, you cannot talk about commutativity. That is why, I asked you, please write the domain and range of the two operators that you speak. Then we can think about commutativity.

Comment: @TenaliRaman I have got why you needed the ranges, thanks. This tides up everything very nicely. But, I think that Hurkyl has already answered my question. Do you have anything to add?

Comment: No, nothing to add. Hurkyl (+1), pretty much has said everything I wanted to convey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $A \Sigma = \Sigma A$ doesn't quite make sense here, because you're using $A$ to mean two different things: on the left, you mean an operator that takes one value $x$ and returns $A(x)$, and on the right you mean an operator that takes many values $(x_i)$ and returns the sequence $(A(x_i))$.

For addition specifically, we would use the term "additive", or possibly in certain contexts "linear". However, there is a generalization of the notion of commutativity that applies to this situation.

Suppose you have an $m \times n$ array of numbers $x_{ij}$, an $m$-ary operation $f$, and an $n$-ary operation $g$.

Then you could apply $f$ on the columns to get an $n$-long sequence which you can plug into $g$

$$ g(f(x_{11}, x_{21}, \ldots, x_{m1}), \cdots, f(x_{1n}, x_{2n}, \ldots, x_{mn}) ) $$

or, you could apply $g$ to the rows to get an $m$-long sequence which you can plug into $f$:

$$ f(g(x_{11}, x_{12}, \ldots, x_{1n}), \cdots, g(x_{m1}, x_{m2}, \ldots, x_{mn}) ) $$

If you get the same value either way, then $f$ and $g$ are said to commute.

As an example, incidentally, the distributive law is precisely the statement that, for each $c$, the binary addition operator commutes with the unary operation "multiply by $c$". Given a 1x2 array of numbers

$$ (a,b) $$

If we apply $+$ across rows, and "multiply (on the right) by $c$" down columns, the two ways of calculating are

$$ (a+b) \cdot c = (a \cdot c) + (b \cdot c) $$

Answer (score 1):

Neither commutativity nor distributivity involve one operation of one argument like (the application of) $A$. Commutativity involves one binary operation ($a\star b=b\star a$), and distributivity involves two binary operations $a\star(b\circ c)=(a\star b)\circ(a\star c))$; this makes the two laws rather uncomparable. The verb "commute" can also be applied to individual elements $a,b$ in case a generally non-commutative operation (often function composition) happens to give the same result when applied to $a,b$ or to $b,a$.

The property of $A$ you state could be described as saying $A$ is compatible with addition, a morphisms of additive groups. There is no other operator of the same kind here to say it commutes with $A$. However one could informally say that $A$ commutes with addition; this would be using a rather vague generalisation of "commuting" since the operations involved are not of the same nature.

Answer (score 0):

The property $A\sum=\sum A$ is probably best described as *additivity*.

Neither commutativity nor distributivity are used in this sense (by mathematicians), as demonstrated ad nauseam in the comments.

Finally, the mention in your post that "A distributes over ∑ iff A and ∑ are commutative" is rather mysterious. Note that $A\sum=\sum A$ might hold even if the underlying "additions" are not commutative (and if they are not, it is true one should probably not be calling them additions) and that I do not even know what is meant by "A is commutative".

Comment: I do not say that A is commutative (alone). I always say with respect to what it is commutative, despite it is always commutative with ∑ in the case that I consider.

Comment: Indeed, a composition law is commutative *alone* and nobody is "commutative with respect to" anybody else. Some transformations "commute" with others--but this is different.

Comment: How is different? I've asked about the case where A commutes with ∑. Are you responding to something different?

Comment: To be commutative $\ne$ To commute with.